# Cmake Internals - target_link_libraries

Tags: dynamic, cmake, linker, dynamic-linking

Suppose I have a directory dir that contains the followings files: libpippo.so and libpippo.a

```
#CMAKE CODE
...
link_directories(${dir})
...
target_link_libraries(program pippo).
```

What happens practically with the command target_link_libraries ?

If am I right, Cmake prefer to use dynamically library if not specified, that's true?

If so, in which way it control that everything is fine? It just check that the library and the required symbolic link are present? It also save the link "dir/libpippo.so" in order to know how where to found the library when the programm will be launched?

Comment: There is nothing to do with CMake. It would just pass `-lpippo` to the compiler, and it is up to compiler what to do with this. AFAIK, it should pick up shared library first.

Comment: that's true. sorry.